# Qt and Boost RPC

Tags: qt, boost, rpc

I'm looking for a good way to connect two systems: 1) a Qt based application running on Ubuntu  and 2) a Boost based application running on another Ubuntu machine.  Both applications use a common library where I would put the common interface code.  I'd like to use a RPC type interface.  I've looked at CORBA and D-Bus but I'm wondering what other people have used or would recommend.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) is a cross-language RPC framework originally developed by Facebook. A prototype I wrote a while ago used it, I think it was quite simple to use (I don't remember any problems). It would be a good choice if you may later want to extend the system with components written in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [ØMQ](http://zeromq.org/).  It is a cross-platform messaging library that, among many other things, "automagically" handles connection issues (including reconnecting in the case of failures).  There are bindings in many languages, and the [czmq](http://czmq.zeromq.org/) library provides a nice high-level C interface for many common uses of ØMQ.

You could easily use the Request-Reply pattern for an RPC framework, but as you read the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), you may find that other patterns are more appropriate.

I did find an [RPC framework](http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com/) built on top of ØMQ, but since you are apparently using C++, this probably won't help you (other than for learning purposes).  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830304/rpc-framework-in-c-utilizing-zeromq).  You could probably quite easily roll your own, if you want.

The license of ØMQ is "LGPLv3+", which is basically LGPL with a static linking exception.  [czmq](http://czmq.zeromq.org/) is moving to the MPLv2, so I would not be surprised if ØMQ follows suit soon.  According to a message from the ØMQ creator, the MPLv2 is very similar to the "LGPLv3+" license, but more acceptable to enterprise lawyers.

You might also consider [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for your interface code.  We used czmq (including zbeacon for automatic node discovery) together with boost serialization, and it works very well.  I have used [XML-RPC](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/) in the past, and I much prefer ØMQ for the connection handling functionality it offers.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Communications Engine (Ice) is a modern and up-to-date RPC Mechanism which supports many languages. You can download it [here](http://www.zeroc.com/download.html). Much of the Ice APIs are defined in Slice which is the specification language for Ice.

Slice (Specification Language for Ice) is the fundamental abstraction mechanism for separating object interfaces from their implementations. Slice establishes a contract between client and server that describes the types and object interfaces used by an application. This description is independent of the implementation language, so it does not matter whether the client is written in the same language as the server.

Slice definitions are compiled for a particular implementation language by a compiler for example for C++.

You can also use XML-RPC. It is a lightweight and easy to use RPC mechanism. You can get it [here](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/).